# Get data from SkyDrive shared Excel file

Tags: php, jquery, excel, onedrive

I have a public shared Excel file on SkyDrive (accessible over a direct link).

Is it possible to read the excel content over jQuery or PHP !? I have three excel sheets so I guess I'll need an API for this !? I found the SkyDrive API (Live Connect) but not sure how to use it as most of the tutorials are for C# or other Microsoft languages.

Or if there is a way to download the excel file over PHP so I could read it with an third-party API?

A simple tutorial link for jQuery or PHP would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This class might help. Its still under development. Could be used to get files from skydrive with ease https://github.com/astroanu/live-api-php-class